# Android Emulator dont respect AppBar shadowColor since Flutter version 2.8.0

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, emulation

Since Flutter version 2.8.0 i get weird UI representation on Android Emulators (Tested on Android API 28 and 30). The emulator draws a shadow below the title that is defined as transparent.

[image]

We use the shadowColor field of the AppBar to set it to Colors.Transparent. On All hardware devices (Android/iOS and iOS Emulator) this results in a hidden shadow of the appbar.

[image]

Can anyone confirm this behavior and have any idea where I can report this or what I could do to be sure this is really just an emulator problem. So far I have not been able to find a hardware device that shows this type of shadow.

Example code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(  
      home: Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
      shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
    ),
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Issues are reported on github: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues they might be able to help you there

Comment: you are right. i opened an issie on github. [#95156](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95156)

Answer (score 0):

There may be default settings for this in different versions or devices, and you will need to set it manually.

```dart
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent, // Colors.red and ...
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
  ));
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: No that wont work. The default is shadow / black color and that is ok. But we override it on several pages. So i expect a shadow on most pages but on pages with a searchbar we override the shadowColor to ransparent so we get the design we desire like in screenshot 2. And it was working all the time and as of today it just stopped working on emulators at the same time i updated Flutter to version 2.8.0 this morning.